# How to execute UNION without sorting? (SQL)

Tags: sql, union, distinct, union-all

`UNION` joins two results and remove duplicates, while `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates.
`UNION` also sort the final output.

What I want is the `UNION ALL` without duplicates and without the sort. Is that possible?

The reason for this is that I want the result of the first query to be on top of the final result, and the second query at the bottom (and each sorted as if they where run individually).

Comment: WHat SQL vendor is this? I don't think the standard requires `UNION ALL` sorts anything - actually the fact it does not sort it usually what makes it a better choice than plain `UNION`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: That's what the OP said (albeit in a jumbled order). He wants to do a UNION but not have the implied sorting.

Comment: @mwan - You are right. I misread the question.

Comment: What does `UNION ALL without duplicates` mean? What if something appears in both result sets? It should be removed from the top, bottom or neither?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I see your point. The first query should have "priority", so duplicates should be removed from bottom

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I notice this question gets quite a lot of views so I'll first address a question you **didn't** ask!

Regarding the title. To achieve a "Sql Union All *with* “distinct”" then simply replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION`. This has the effect of removing duplicates.

For your specific question, given the clarification "The first query should have "priority", so duplicates should be removed from bottom" you can use

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       MIN(grp) AS source_group
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS grp,
               col1,
               col2
        FROM   t1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS grp,
               col1,
               col2
        FROM   t2) AS t
GROUP  BY col1,
          col2
ORDER  BY MIN(grp),
          col1
```

Comment: +1 exposing the sort order to the caller is good practice anyhow.

Comment: @onedaywhen - Thanks for the edit. Missed that in the question.

Comment: This works if eliminating duplicates within the individual queries is all that's required, but not if removing duplicates across both queries is also required.

Comment: @Damien - Agreed. Just posted a comment asking for clarification on this.

Comment: I take back my +1 -- see my answer, which 'corrects' @dursun's answer :)

Answer (score 11):

"UNION also sort the final output" - only as an implementation artifact. It is by *no means* guaranteed to perform the sort, and if you need a particular sort order, you should specify it with an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise, the output order is whatever is most convenient for the server to provide.

As such, your request for a function that performs a `UNION ALL` but that removes duplicates is easy - it's called `UNION`.

---

From your clarification, you also appear to believe that a `UNION ALL` will return all of the results from the first query before the results of the subsequent queries. This is *also* not guaranteed. Again, the only way to achieve a particular order is to specify it using an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, 1 AS sort_order
  FROM table1
 EXCEPT 
SELECT *, 1 AS sort_order
  FROM table2
UNION
SELECT *, 1 AS sort_order
  FROM table1
 INTERSECT 
SELECT *, 1 AS sort_order
  FROM table2
UNION
SELECT *, 2 AS sort_order
  FROM table2
 EXCEPT 
SELECT *, 2 AS sort_order
  FROM table1
ORDER BY sort_order;
```

But the real answer is: other than the `ORDER BY` clause, the sort order will by arbitrary and not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

Consider these tables (Standard SQL code, runs on SQL Server 2008):

```
WITH A 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1), 
                     (2), 
                     (3), 
                     (4), 
                     (5), 
                     (6) 
             ) AS T (col)
     ),
     B 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (9), 
                     (8), 
                     (7), 
                     (6), 
                     (5), 
                     (4) 
             ) AS T (col)
     ), ...
```

The desired effect is this to sort table `A` by `col` ascending, sort table `B` by `col` descending then unioning the two, removing duplicates, retaining order before the union and leaving table `A` results on the "top" with table `B` on the "bottom" e.g. (pesudo code)

```
(
 SELECT *
   FROM A
  ORDER 
     BY col
)
UNION
(
 SELECT *
   FROM B
  ORDER 
     BY col DESC
);
```

Of course, this won't work in SQL because there can only be one `ORDER BY` clause and it can only be applied to the top level table expression (or whatever the output of a `SELECT` query is known as; I call it the "resultset").

The first thing to address is the intersection between the two tables, in this case the values `4`, `5` and `6`. How the intersection should be sorted needs to be specified in SQL code, therefore it is desirable that  the designer specifies this too! (i.e. the person asking the question, in this case).

The implication in this case would seem to be that the intersection ("duplicates") should be sorted within the results for table A. Therefore, the sorted  resultset should look like this:

```
      VALUES (1), -- A including intersection, ascending
             (2), -- A including intersection, ascending
             (3), -- A including intersection, ascending
             (4), -- A including intersection, ascending
             (5), -- A including intersection, ascending
             (6), -- A including intersection, ascending
             (9), -- B only, descending 
             (8), -- B only, descending  
             (7), -- B only, descending
```

Note in SQL "top" and "bottom" has no inferent meaning and a table (other than a resultset) has no inherent ordering. Also (to cut a long story short) consider that `UNION` removes duplicate rows by implication and must be applied before `ORDER BY`. The conclusion has to be that each table's sort order must be explicitly defined by exposing a sort order column(s) **before** being unioned. For this we can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowed function e.g.

```
     ...
     A_ranked
     AS
     (
      SELECT col, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) AS sort_order_1
        FROM A                      -- include the intersection
     ),
     B_ranked
     AS
     (
      SELECT *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col DESC) AS sort_order_1
        FROM B
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (           -- exclude the intersection
                         SELECT * 
                           FROM A
                          WHERE A.col = B.col 
                        )
     )
SELECT *, 1 AS sort_order_0 
  FROM A_ranked
UNION
SELECT *, 2 AS sort_order_0 
  FROM B_ranked
ORDER BY sort_order_0, sort_order_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select T.Col1, T.Col2, T.Sort
from 
    (
      select T.Col1,
             T.Col2,
             T.Sort,
             rank() over(partition by T.Col1, T.Col2 order by T.Sort) as rn
      from
          (
            select Col1, Col2, 1 as Sort
            from Table1
            union all
            select Col1, Col2, 2
            from Table2
          ) as T
    ) as T
where T.rn = 1    
order by T.Sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (

      SELECT  column1, column2 FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  column1, column2 FROM Table2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  column1, column2 FROM Table3

  ) X ORDER BY Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort is used to eliminate the duplicates, and is implicit for `DISTINCT` and `UNION` queries (but not `UNION ALL`) - you could still specify the columns you'd prefer to order by if you need them sorted by specific columns.

For example, if you wanted to sort by the result sets, you could introduce an additional column, and sort by that first:

```
SELECT foo, bar, 1 as ResultSet
FROM Foo
WHERE bar = 1
UNION
SELECT foo, bar, 2 as ResultSet
FROM Foo
WHERE bar = 3
UNION
SELECT foo, bar, 3 as ResultSet
FROM Foo
WHERE bar = 2
ORDER BY ResultSet
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your tables are table1 and table2 respectively,
and your solution is;

```
(select * from table1 MINUS select * from table2)
UNION ALL
(select * from table2 MINUS select * from table1)
```

Comment: Won't this eliminate all rows that have duplicates? I rather think they want to just remove the duplicates!

Comment: See my answer for a correction (I'm using Standard SQL's `EXCEPT` rather than Oracle's `MINUS` but that's not the correction :)

Answer (score -1):

1,1:

`select 1 from dual
union all select 1 from dual`

1:

`select 1 from dual
union select 1 from dual`

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```
Select distinct name from  (SELECT r.name FROM outsider_role_mapping orm1 
    union all
SELECT r.name FROM user_role_mapping orm2
) tmp;
```